# How to use transformer via createQueryBuilder - TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nest

I'm working on NestJS. I want to transform my datetime via createQueryBuilder.

For the repository I can easily use the transformer on the entity like this,

```
  @Column({ 
    name: 'expire_date',
    transformer: {
      to: (value:Date) => value,
      from: (value:Date) => value == null ? value : moment(value,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toDate()
    } 
  })
  expireDate: Date;
```

If I get the data from repository like,

```
const data = await this.produtRepository({where: { id: id }});
```

the **expireDate** column will convert the datetime format for me automatically.

But I cannot find any way to do it via queryBuilder yet.

Here is my example of the queryBuilder Code,

```
let product = await this.produtRepository.createQueryBuilder('product')
.innerJoin('product.category', 'category')
.select([
 'product.id AS "productId"',
 'product.expireDate AS "expireDate"'
])
.getRawMany();
```

the expireDate of the product result will be

"expireDate": "2023-10-23T17:07:20.000Z"

How can I do to get the expireDate in YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss like the repository can do ?

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve data using createQueryBuilder, the result set is returned as raw data, and thus, the transformer specified in your entity definition is not applied. If you want to format the expireDate in the YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format directly within the query using TypeORM’s createQueryBuilder, you will need to handle it as part of your query logic.One way to do this is to use the database’s native date formatting functions within your query.

```
let product = await this.produtRepository.createQueryBuilder('product')
.innerJoin('product.category', 'category')
.select([
 'product.id AS "productId"',
 'DATE_FORMAT(product.expireDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AS "expireDate"'
])
.getRawMany();
```

note that the query depends on your databse.
`DATE_FORMAT` in `mysql` and `to_char` in `postgresql`